# Как вывести элемент массива a на позиции, равной сумме позиций минимального и максимального элемента массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Нужно вывести элемент массива a на позиции, равной сумме
позиций минимального и максимального элемента массива.
Input: В первой строке вводится n (1 ⩽ n ⩽ 50) — количество чисел в массиве a.
Во второй строке вводится n чисел ai (0 ⩽ ai ⩽ 50) — элементы массива a.
Если максимальных или минимальных значений несколько, используйте первый из них.
Output: Выведите искомый элемент или строку «Vne massiva», если искомый индекс выходит за границы
массива.
примеры:
ввод:
5
1 5 2 4 3
вывод:
2
ввод:
3
1 2 3
вывод: Vne massiva

Программа работает неправильно, подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

```
   #include <iostream>
using std :: cin;
using std :: cout;
struct element
{
  int index = 0;
  int *value;
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    int * A = new int [n];;
    element max, min;
    min.value = A;
    max.value = A;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> A[i];
        if(A[i] < *min.value){
            min.index = i;
            min.value = &A[i];
        }
         if(A[i] > *max.value){
            max.index = i;
            max.value = &A[i];
        }
    }
    if(max.index + min.index < n)
    {
    cout << A[max.index + min.index];
    }
 
    else
    {
    cout << "Vne massiva";
    }
     delete [] A;
    }
```

Comment: VLA нет в плюсах, хотя некоторые компиляторы в них умеют.

Answer (score 0):

Второе сравнение неправильное: `if(mas[i] < *max.value)`. Должен быть знак `>`.

Comment: к сожалению, она так же работает не до конца правильно

Comment: Ну и в `if(max.index + min.index <= n)`, если сумма индексов `n`, то будет выход за границы, должно быть строгое неравенство.

Comment: убрал VLA, ну и знаки в If, но все равно  работает не до конца